# Karate framework for larger data load porcess using post soap service

Tags: karate

I have a requirement in which 10,000 plus rows of data needs to be mapped for a SOAP xml post service using karate's feature file examples table. Since data maintenance is easy using csv file, I used below code (copied only relevant code, xml is embedded in feature file) for scenario outline,

- def csvData = read('test.csv')
  Examples:
  | csvData |
  Execution hits performance issue, after 800 transactions and test fails.
  Please advise, if there is any way to achieve this large data load process using Karate and web services post.

Comment: the only way to find out is for you to give us a way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - otherwise, please figure this out on your own. note there are others who have done this in the past, see this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/661

Comment: and in my opinion. this is not testing, you seem to be doing something else. look at karate's gatling support or maybe Karate is the wrong tool for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the CSV / Dynamic Scenario Outline because it would have to load all the rows into memory.

Use `karate.repeat()` https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops - and use a second feature to make the final request, similar to data-driven testing: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

In the loop you can get the current index, and write some function to get that particular data, it can be from a CSV or even a database.