# Karate Execution getting stuck in the report generation step

Tags: karate

I am executing my karate suite from teamcity. I have started facing an issue when i had to add some data csv files with 1700 rows and around 10 columns.

I got Out of memory error while local execution. I added argLine params and increased heapSize to 6G. In local I managed to solve the error.

When I moved this to continuous integration environment even with argline params 6G heap size, its getting stuck. Interesting fact is even if I exclude these large files tests using tags its getting stuck.

I am using parallel executer with 2 threads(I also tried with 1 thread). Also I use cucumber reports.

From the analysis what i understand is karate completes the test execution just before generating the reports json and cucumber reports it gets stuck.

I have tried to remove those huge CSV files and tried to put the data directly in examples inside my feature file. Still it gets stuck.

I have managed to fix this in my local, but it seems to be potetial issue. Any suggestions.

Total number of tests am running is 4500.

Comment: give us a way to replicate please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62078626/143475

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on this but I would say break down your tests into many classes  (you could start with having 2 runners instead of just 1) and have each class only call a portion of the .feature files you have.   It is possible breaking your tests into multiple classes running parts of your test cases might relieve the memory problem.

For example:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/GreetingRunner.java